How to increase Minsdkversion on Android Studio Flutter project
When I try to add any new activity to an existing new flutter project in Android Studio, it says project not ready, minSdk >= 16.
I created a new flutter project, fully new with flutter create name. When I try to add a widget activity to the android/app folder in Android Studio it says project not ready, mindSdk >= 16. I've tried changing the SDK from Project Structure, changing local.properties and build.gradle, I even changed the default Flutter project settings. I've tried this with mutliple flutter projects and created them from the command line and the Android Studio project creator.

go to build.gradle in app folder of android folder of your project and change it manually

Try to run flutter doctor once. You can also try to Invalidate cache in Android Studio. I hope you have already tried upgrading the SDK version in the Gradle file. If this issue still exists, please give us the exact error log.
